# OEM sound card with no drivers or support

Tags: drivers, sound-card

I thought my sound card was going out so I bought a sound card online. Everything seemed to work ok, I do have sound. But after a few months, I noticed the extra software that downloaded with the sound card drivers didn't work.

I ended up contacting creative and after a month of e-mail support, they asked for the serial number and/or model number. Their reply back was I had purchased an OEM sound card and they could not provide support for that, and informed me that that is why their drivers and software didn't work. They informed me that I had to contact the company that distributed the sound card and install their software.

Is there anything I can do to find out who distributed this sound card, or is there anything I can do to get other features to work?

I have 4 speakers and a sub but only 2 speakers produce sound. The only control I have is the volume.

Creative's driver update program will find my sound card, download updates and even added software, but if I try to click on a downloaded program like Creative's Toolbox or Media Center, I get an error that it cannot find the devise. That is why I contacted creative in the first place.

---

**EDIT**

Thanks for the responses everyone. Here's an update.

I thought I'd go thru my old computer stuff for my classes at school. I have a lot of old stuff saved, boxes and cables and stuff. I found the box the sound card came in. It looks like a box you'd buy at the store, like Best Buy or CompUSA.

I worked with creative for such a long time, it went past the point of being able to return it to the junk online store this shipped from. The box did have an install CD, so I thought I'd start over to reinstall the drivers and software that shipped with the card.

I noticed that the install would uninstall a program, then reinstall it. so I thought things were working out. But no good. Everything still works but the programs were still bad. I'd get an error trying to load them - not found.

I'll look on the card the next time I get a chance and see if I can spot any kind of name on it.

Comment: You are going to have to deal with your issues with Creative.  I will tell you there is NO reason their drivers should not work.

Comment: Ramhound - its an OEM card.  Creative has no idea what was done to the card after being sold to the vendor.  And they certainly have no responsibility for it.

Comment: Contact the place you got the card from online. Get you money back if the card was supposed to be Creative-compatible or find out where to get drivers for it if it isn't (and therefore will need its own driver).

Answer (score 0):

Check the card carefully for a maker name.  It is usually there but if not, you may be looking at buying another card.  I have seen some where it is simply three letters stenciled on the card.

Good luck.